How to use "include" directory in PlatformIO correctly?
I'm working on ESP32 camera with the espidf framework.
I separated private library for each components, for example camera, uart, udp.
They have a pattern like this:
projectname/lib/camera/camera.h
projectname/lib/camera/camera.c
projectname/lib/uart/uart.h
projectname/lib/uart/uart.c
projectname/lib/udp/udp.h
projectname/lib/udp/udp.c
...

Therefore, projectname/include is empty since the header file is already stored inside the private library.

Here is the example of wifi as private library content in the header and the code:
// projectname/lib/uwc_wifi.c
#include "uwc_wifi.h"

static esp_err_t err;

/* FreeRTOS event group to signal when we are connected*/
static EventGroupHandle_t s_wifi_event_group;
static int s_retry_num;

char WIFI_SSID[32] = "uwc";
char WIFI_PASW[32] = "87654321";
bool uwcWifiIsInit = false;

static void event_handler(void *arg, esp_event_base_t event_base,
                          int32_t event_id, void *event_data) {
  if (event_base == WIFI_EVENT && event_id == WIFI_EVENT_STA_START) {
    esp_wifi_connect();
  } else if (event_base == WIFI_EVENT &&
             event_id == WIFI_EVENT_STA_DISCONNECTED) {
    uwcWifiIsInit = false;
    if (s_retry_num < MAX_TRY) {
      esp_wifi_connect();
      s_retry_num++;
      if (!(s_retry_num % 4)) {
        ESP_LOGI(uwc_tag_wifi, "Connect AP '%s'|'%s' attempt: %i", WIFI_SSID,
                 WIFI_PASW, MAX_TRY - s_retry_num);
      }
    } else {
      xEventGroupSetBits(s_wifi_event_group, WIFI_FAIL_BIT);
    }
  } else if (event_base == IP_EVENT && event_id == IP_EVENT_STA_GOT_IP) {
    ip_event_got_ip_t *event = (ip_event_got_ip_t *)event_data;
    ESP_LOGI(uwc_tag_wifi, "got ip:" IPSTR, IP2STR(&event->ip_info.ip));
    s_retry_num = 0;
    xEventGroupSetBits(s_wifi_event_group, WIFI_CONNECTED_BIT);
  }
}

esp_err_t uwc_wifi_init_sta(void) {
  if (uwcWifiIsInit) {
    ESP_LOGW(uwc_tag_wifi, "WiFi already initialized!");
    return ESP_OK;
  }

  s_wifi_event_group = xEventGroupCreate();

  ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_netif_init());

  ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_loop_create_default());
  uwcWifiStaNetif = esp_netif_create_default_wifi_sta();

  wifi_init_config_t cfg = WIFI_INIT_CONFIG_DEFAULT();
  err = esp_wifi_init(&cfg);
  ESP_ERROR_CHECK(err);

  esp_event_handler_instance_t instance_any_id;
  esp_event_handler_instance_t instance_got_ip;

  ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_handler_instance_register(
      WIFI_EVENT, ESP_EVENT_ANY_ID, &event_handler, NULL, &instance_any_id));
  ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_handler_instance_register(
      IP_EVENT, IP_EVENT_STA_GOT_IP, &event_handler, NULL, &instance_got_ip));

  wifi_config_t wifi_config = {
      .sta =
          {
              .threshold.authmode = WIFI_AUTH_OPEN,
          },
  };

  strncpy((char *)wifi_config.sta.ssid, (char *)&WIFI_SSID[0], 32);
  if (strcmp("open", (char *)&WIFI_PASW[0])) {  // Jika password wifi adalah
                                                // open maka tanpa password!
    wifi_config.sta.threshold.authmode = WIFI_AUTH_WPA2_PSK;
    strncpy((char *)wifi_config.sta.password, (char *)&WIFI_PASW[0], 64);
  }

  ESP_LOGI(uwc_tag_wifi, "WIFI AUTH: %i", wifi_config.sta.threshold.authmode);

  ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_set_mode(WIFI_MODE_STA));
  ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_set_config(WIFI_IF_STA, &wifi_config));
  ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_start());

  ESP_LOGI(uwc_tag_wifi, "wifi_init_sta finished!");

  /* Waiting until either the connection is established (WIFI_CONNECTED_BIT) or
   * connection failed for the maximum number of re-tries (WIFI_FAIL_BIT). The
   * bits are set by event_handler() (see above) */
  EventBits_t bits = xEventGroupWaitBits(s_wifi_event_group,
                                         WIFI_CONNECTED_BIT | WIFI_FAIL_BIT,
                                         pdFALSE, pdFALSE, portMAX_DELAY);

  /* xEventGroupWaitBits() returns the bits before the call returned, hence we
   * can test which event actually happened. */
  if (bits & WIFI_CONNECTED_BIT) {
    ESP_LOGI(uwc_tag_wifi, "Connected to ap SSID:%s password:%s", WIFI_SSID,
             WIFI_PASW);
    if (esp_netif_get_ip_info(uwcWifiStaNetif, &uwcWifiIpInfo)) {
      ESP_LOGE(uwc_tag_wifi, "Error getting IP info!");
      return ESP_FAIL;
    }
    ESP_LOGI(uwc_tag_wifi, "WiFi has been initialized!");
    uwcWifiIsInit = true;
  } else if (bits & WIFI_FAIL_BIT) {
    ESP_LOGI(uwc_tag_wifi, "Failed to connect to SSID:%s, password:%s",
             WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASW);
    uwcWifiIsInit = false;
  } else {
    ESP_LOGE(uwc_tag_wifi, "UNEXPECTED EVENT");
    uwcWifiIsInit = false;
  }

  return err;
}

esp_err_t uwc_wifi_deinit_sta(void) {
  if (!uwcWifiIsInit) {
    ESP_LOGE(uwc_tag_wifi, "WiFi already deinitialized!");
    return ESP_OK;
  }

  err = esp_wifi_deinit();

  if (!err) {
    ESP_LOGI(uwc_tag_wifi, "WiFi has been deinitialized!");
    uwcWifiIsInit = false;
    return err;
  }

  ESP_LOGE(uwc_tag_wifi, "WiFi init failure!");
  return err;
}

And here is the header located at projectname/lib/uwc_wifi.h
#ifndef __UWC_WIFI_H__
#define __UWC_WIFI_H__

#include <string.h>

#include "esp_event.h"
#include "esp_log.h"
#include "esp_system.h"
#include "esp_wifi.h"
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/event_groups.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "lwip/err.h"
#include "lwip/sys.h"
#include "nvs_flash.h"
#include "uwc_tag.h"

/* The event group allows multiple bits for each event, but we only care about
 * two events:
 * - we are connected to the AP with an IP
 * - we failed to connect after the maximum amount of retries */
#define WIFI_CONNECTED_BIT BIT0
#define WIFI_FAIL_BIT BIT1

// WiFI Setup
#define MAX_TRY 20

extern char WIFI_SSID[32];
extern char WIFI_PASW[32];
esp_netif_t* uwcWifiStaNetif;
esp_netif_ip_info_t uwcWifiIpInfo;  // IP when connected to AP.
extern bool uwcWifiIsInit;          // WiFI initialization status.

/**
 * @brief WiFi STA init.
 */
esp_err_t uwc_wifi_init_sta(void);

/**
 * @brief WiFi STA deinit (still bug).
 */
esp_err_t uwc_wifi_deinit_sta(void);

#endif

So, Does it mean I don't need the projectname/include folder?
